# Конструкция if php

Tags: php

Есть такой код:

```
function DefineCountryUser($lang_number = 0){
 if (empty($_SESSION['lg']) && empty($lang_number)) {

// сюда не заходит
} elseif (!empty($lang_number)) {
// сюда заходит несмотря на то что в die($lang_number); ничего не выводит
}
```

}

В чем причина.

Comment: Что выдаст:  

    var_dump($_SESSION["lg"]);
    var_dump($lang_number);
?

Comment: Severity: Notice. 
Message: Undefined index: lg. 
Filename: helpers/helper.php. 
Line Number: 919 // Для $_SESSION["lg"] - она удаляется выше 

NULL int(1) //var_dump($lang_number);

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю empty возвращает true
Попробуйте

```
if (empty($_SESSION['lg']) && empty($lang_number)) {
```

заменить на

```
if (empty($_SESSION['lg']) && !$lang_number) {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function DefineCountryUser($lang_number = 0){
 if(!isset($_SESSION['lg'])){
    echo "not found LG index";
    return 0;
 }
 elseif (empty($_SESSION['lg']) && empty($lang_number)) {
    echo "good 1";
 }
 elseif (!empty($lang_number)) {
    echo "good 2";
 }
}
```